# How to assign the Renderbuffer/textures to the correct fragment shader outputs?

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

This snippet belongs to an initialization function, and comes from [OpenGL Programming Guide V4.3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321773039), page 188:

```
enum {Color, Depth, NumRenderbuffers };
GLuint framebuffer, renderbuffer[NumRenderbuffers]

void init()
{
    glGenRenderbuffers(NumRenderbuffers, renderbuffer);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer[Color]);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, 256,256);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer[Depth]);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 256,256);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer[Color]);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer[Depth]);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

How would I go about directing the fragment shader output to the correct renderbuffers?

I know we are supposed to use something like this:

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;
layout (location = 1) out float depth;
```

However, I don't understand a few things:

Question 1: What are the 0 and 1 in the above lines, exactly? Are they the GLuint of the respective  renderbuffers/textures?

Question 2: Do these 0 and 1 have anything to do with the `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTX` targets of the FBO? Normally I see people using `layout (location = x)` with the corresponding `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTX`, but what would you do if you also had a depth texture, that has the attachment `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`? What `layout (location = x)` does it get? Normally I see people setting `layout (location = 0) out float depth`, or some variant, while doing absolutely nothing in the framebuffer initialization to justify the 0.

Question 2: Since the GLuints get assigned by OpenGL during initialization and might change depending on what you initialize before them, what is the safe way of determining the GLuint of your renderbuffer in the shader (to put in the correct `layout (location = x)` line)?

Question 3: I have a simple shadow map implementation with a depth texture bound to a framebuffer such as that. It is the only attachment to its FBO, and I attach it with the `glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, m_shadowMap, 0);` line. While trying to understand this `layout` situation, I have both set the fragment shader to use an "unused" location number, like `layout (location = 5) out float fragmentdepth;`, and also simply commented the layout part out, leaving just `out float fragmentdepth`. Both of these changes did absolutely nothing: The shadowmap still got created/used perfectly. Why?

Comment: I can try and answer some of your questions, its been a long time since i have written my framebuffer code, but i run into the same unknowns.

first i think you cannot directly write into the depth texture / cannot bind it to the framebuffer, the pipeline uses it as the usual depth texture, but you can read from it later. if you specificly want to write into a sudo-depth texture, write the depth value to a normal texture and use it as a depth texture later.

Comment: second, the binding to buffers happens in glDrawBuffers, as far as i remember: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawBuffers.xhtml  there you have your location = 0.. and so on color attachments.

This should also answer question 2, your cpu code binds them, so you have control over them.

Comment: My shadowmap is a depth texture, and for writing and reading I bind it to my own FBO, not the default one. You can read/write depth from a texture bound to a FBO without any problems, also. Just malloc it like this: 

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, shadowMapWidth, shadowMapHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

And attach it like this:

glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, m_shadowMap, 0);

Then sample like a normal 2D texture

Comment: For question 3: my shadow buffer has no color attachment, my fragment shader does not draw anything. i just push the geometry through the pipeline until the Z test and then take the framebuffers depth texture

Comment: what i was talking about in my first comment was the specific slot for the depth texture. if you bind a texture as depth to a FBO, you cannot write into it form a fragment shader AFAIK.

Comment: Yes you can write to it, and that binding is part of my question. I'm using that exact method to draw and read my shadow maps and it works just fine. Also, if glDrawBuffers is what is used to indicate which renderbuffer/textures the fragment shaders should write into, how do you indicate a depth or stencil attachment? They don't seem to be valid arguments to it